# fs.createReadStream takes relative path even while passing absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying an npm package 'unzipper' to extract the zipped file. unzipper uses fs to read the stream.
So the path which i provided was absolute path, and the fs merged it with the relative.

```
fs.createReadStream('‪C://Test//zipedfolder.zip')
  .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: '‪C://Test//Newfolder' }));
```

here fs is taking the relative path as `C:\zipExtraction\‪‪C:\Test\zipedfolder.zip` and throws the error 'no such file or directory'

```
C:\zipExtraction
```

this folder contains the nodejs project.

Any suggestion to avoid adding the relative path.